# Copy and Rename files in WPF C#

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm using `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` in my **WPF** application to select images. When user select an image, I'm displaying file name of selected file in a textbox as below.

```
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Title = "Select image";
            fileDialog.InitialDirectory = "";
            fileDialog.Filter = "Image Files (*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.bmp,*.png)|*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png";
            fileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
            fileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtImagePath.Text = fileDialog.FileName;
            }
```

I have a button as `Save` in my application. When user click on this button, I need to **rename** this file to another name and **copy** it to another directory in my hard drive.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: System.IO.File.Copy(...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) and methods in the [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) to extract the relevant part of your file

```
string newDir = @"D:\temp";
string curFile = Path.GetFileName(txtImagePath.Text);
string newPathToFile = Path.Combine(newDir, curFile);
File.Copy(txtImagePath.Text, newPathToFile);
```

Now the rename operation on the current dir using [File.Move](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-move)

```
string curDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(textImagePath.Text);
File.Move(txtImagePath.Text, Path.Combine(curDir, "NewNameForFile.txt"));
```

This code could be improved introducing some error handling

If you want to copy directly the old file in the new dir using the new name then you could write simply

```
string newPathToFile = @"D:\temp\NewNameForFile.txt";
File.Copy(txtImagePath.Text, newPathToFile);
```

and then do the rename on the current dir.

Comment: Your answer is working. But this rename the file in original location. not the file in copied location. as your example, i need to rename the file in `D:\temp`.

Answer (score 2):

How about using:
    System.IO.File.Copy

Alternatively, you can start a batch file, using `processInfo`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File.Copy`. Here are the details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx. It takes the source file and copies it to a destination, possibly under a new name.